# Spring MVC + Hibernate + Maven : Multiple annotations found in bean declaration

Tags: xml, spring, xml-namespaces

I am developing a web application in Spring MVC based on maven with hibernate using eclipse juno.
When I am trying to configure hibernate in servlet-context.xml showing error as follows :

**cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.**

servlet-context.xml looks like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.webworld.crm" />


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />  
  <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />  
  <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />  
  <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />  
</bean>  

<bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

    <property name="mappingResources">  
    <list>  
    <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
    </list>  
    </property>  

    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">MySQL5Dialect</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

        </props>  
    </property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="d" class="com.javatpoint.EmployeeDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
</bean>
</beans>
```

The file structure is as follows :

[image]

Please answer this as soon as possible.

Comment: The problem is you specified `spring-mvc.xsd` as the root namespace, the namespace you can use without a prefix. So `<annotation-driven />` corresponds to `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. However there is no `<bean>` tag in `spring-mvc.xsd` that is in `spring-beans.xsd`. To make it work you need to either prefix all your `<bean />`, `<property />` etc. with `beans:` as that is what you specified for the `spring-beans.xsd` as prefix. Or switch the root namespace to `spring-beans.xsd` and prefix `<annotation-driven />` with `mvc`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your time but if you please elaborate this by rewrite the code, it is more helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

The problem is you specified `spring-mvc.xsd` as the root namespace, the namespace you can use without a prefix. So `<annotation-driven />` corresponds to `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. However there is no `<bean>` tag in `spring-mvc.xsd` as that is in `spring-beans.xsd`.

To make it work you need to either prefix all your `<bean />`, `<property />` etc. with `beans:` as that is what you specified for the `spring-beans.xsd` as prefix. Or switch the root namespace to `spring-beans.xsd` and prefix `<annotation-driven />` with `mvc`.

**Example with `beans:` prefix**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

**Example with different root namespace**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but when I use mvc prefix it is showing error like "The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound." I have use the code "Example with different root namespace" you have mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Oops forgot to replace `xmlns:beans` with `xmlns:mvc`. Answer updated.

Comment: Also the issue you have has basically nothing todo with Spring but is just how XML works.

Comment: Sorry to say but after updated the same it is showing error with resources : "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources] Offending resource: file [D:/AngularTest/WebWorld/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/
  appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
 - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources]
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'."

Comment: Please read my answer and readup on how xml and xml namespaces work you knowledge seems to be lacking in that area. Just not only rename `xmlns:beans` to `xmlns:mvc` as that obviously will not work.

Comment: Don't angry man every thing is fine now when I add version of .xsd.

Comment: You should use the version less xsd, as that garantuees the latest available version for the spring version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

For first bean definition you have given **beans:**bean prefix as below.

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

But for rest of all bean definitions you have missed to provide the prefix "beans".
I think this could be problem as parser is not able to identify this tag. Please try giving prefix to all the tags and try.

Comment: No but I don't want to use this old technique i am updating my question also. If I use your recommended code it will show me error in front of every bean.

Comment: Ok. Try reordering the xml schema definitions in first tag, with beans schema as default and rest with their prefixes. Here beans tag is part of beans xml namespace.

Comment: Now please see the question again error is now changed.

Comment: Your starting schema definition should be as below, and change all other tag prefixes according to this. <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

Comment: For reference you can see the below URL.
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/contact-webapp-spring-config.html